# elegant way to get Scatter plot in R or matplotlib

Tags: python, r, graph, visualization, scatter-plot

I have a file as follows:

```
"ID"    "method1"   "method2"
"ABCD00005178"  -2.226646256    -2.14728
"ABCD00064724"  -2.460661389    -2.32005
"ABCD00169298"  -3.007943799    -2.00823
"ABCD00219070"  -2.68641563 -2.62434
"ABCD00220763"  -2.416688099    -2.38739
"ABCD00225740"  -2.36953104 -2.27758
"ABCD00226317"  -3.960254576    -3.92418
"ABCD00229829"  -3.564266939    -3.50151
"ABCD00229913"  -3.897553385    -3.98728
"ABCD00231004"  -3.507735931    -3.55717
"ABCD00231061"  -5.480421407    -5.38307
"ABCD00233156"  -2.363380193    -2.32521
"ABCD00233813"  -4.468308431    -4.30908
"ABCD00237623"  -4.113207121    -3.98899
"ABCD00241261"  -2.134610592    -2.03762
"ABCD00243457"  -3.558826293    -3.45873
"ABCD00248564"  -2.402259151    -2.08466
```

I am trying to plot a scatter plot in R as follows.

```
x <- read.delim("filename.txt", row.names=1, header=T)
plot(x)
```

I am getting a scatter plot but I am unable to differentiate the two data points for each ID. My file contains over 1000 rows and I want to show that the values obtained from the two methods are similar or differs. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If I were approaching this, I would use `hist` to plot the differences between `x$method1` and `x$method2`, and then I would use `subset` to figure out which observations had the large deviations.

Comment: histogram will will plot frequencies i guess...I meed to compare the values for each ID to see whether positively correlated or not. The cor() can be used to get the correlation between two methods..but looking for a scatter plot.

Comment: Are you looking for more than a scatterplot where the x-axis is `x$method1` and the y-axis is `x$method2`?

Comment: I am looking for color coding. and just looking for an intuitive plot.

Answer (score 1):

Each dot is 'Two data points for each ID'. Not exactly, x-coordinates is `method1` and y-coordinates is `method2`. To see if there are correlated, simple look if the dots appears to aligned to a straight line. If you need a statistics test, do a linear regression.

```
> x <- read.delim("temp.txt", header=T, sep=' ')
> plot(x$method1, x$method2)
> text(x$method1, x$method2, x$ID, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Linear regression:

```
> fit <- lm(method1~method2, data=x)
> plot(x$method1, x$method2)
> abline(fit)
```

[image]
Color scatter:

```
> plot(x$method1, x$method2, col=x$ID)
```

[image]